# Assistance needed with Jquery if statement for calculated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

ow would I write a script that would allow the option of having the user enter a percentage and a dollar amount is calculated or a dollar amount and a percentage is calculated?  Currently my form only allows for the entry of a percentage and the dollar amount is calculated, but I need for the user to be able to enter either and have the form automatically calculate the missing element. Here is the code that I am using to calculate the dollar amount:

```
    script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".TextBox").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('TextBoxSelected');
  },function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('TextBoxSelected');
  }).change(function(){
    calculate();
  });
});
function getFldValue(fldValue) {
  return isNaN(fldValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(fldValue);
}
function calculate() {
  var property_SPrice = getFldValue($('#property_SPrice').val());
  var price = getFldValue($('#price').val());

  var REO_sale_percentage    = getFldValue($('#REO_sale_percentage').val());
  var REO_sale_dollars       = getFldValue($('#REO_sale_dollars').val());
  var REO_sale_bonus_dollars = getFldValue($('#REO_sale_bonus_dollars').val());
  var REO_sale_fixed_dollars = getFldValue($('#REO_sale_fixed_dollars').val());
  var REO_sale_total_dollars = getFldValue($('#REO_sale_total_dollars').val());


  var REO_list_percentage    = getFldValue($('#REO_list_percentage').val());
  var REO_list_dollars       = getFldValue($('#REO_list_dollars').val());
  var REO_list_bonus_dollars = getFldValue($('#REO_list_bonus_dollars').val());
  var REO_list_fixed_dollars = getFldValue($('#REO_list_fixed_dollars').val());
  var REO_list_total_dollars = getFldValue($('#REO_list_total_dollars').val());

  var gr_comm_percentage     = getFldValue($('#gr_comm_percentage').val());
  var gr_comm_dollars        = getFldValue($('#gr_comm_dollars').val());
  var gr_bonus_dollars       = getFldValue($('#gr_bonus_dollars').val());
  var gr_fixed_dollars       = getFldValue($('#gr_fixed_dollars').val());
  var gr_total_dollars       = getFldValue($('#gr_total_dollars').val());   

  $('#price').val(property_SPrice);
  $('#gr_comm_percentage').val(REO_list_percentage + REO_sale_percentage);

  $('#gr_comm_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_list_dollars + REO_sale_dollars));
  $('#REO_list_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_list_percentage/100*price));
  $('#REO_sale_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_sale_percentage/100*price));
  $('#gr_fixed_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_list_fixed_dollars + REO_sale_fixed_dollars));
  $('#gr_bonus_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_list_bonus_dollars + REO_sale_bonus_dollars));
  $('#gr_total_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_sale_total_dollars + REO_list_total_dollars));
  $('#REO_sale_total_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_sale_dollars + REO_sale_fixed_dollars + REO_sale_bonus_dollars));
  $('#REO_list_total_dollars').val(getFldValue(REO_list_dollars + REO_list_fixed_dollars + REO_list_bonus_dollars));



}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
var fieldvalue= //get the field value
if(fieldvalue.indexOf('%') != -1){
   var percentage = parseFloat(fieldvalue.replace('%',''));
   //do whatever you need with that value
}
```